# FRA - Transit between 1B and 1C, reclear security/immigration?

Tags: transit, connecting-flights, frankfurt, fra

How long will I need for a non-schengen to non-schengen transit from Frankfurt 1B to 1C? Will I have to expect longer travel times due to immigration or security checks?

I couldn't find a definite answer online, even more so as I expect older resources to be outdated after the opening of the 1C skyline stop in 2017. This [one](https://abouttravel.ch/reisebranche/transport-luft-land/umsteigen-in-frankfurt-wird-effizienter/) (in German) suggests that a non-stop transit is possible, but it talks about 1A and 1C and does not give actual travel times. [Another source](https://www.airport-fra.com/terminal-2.php) reads as if the skyline stop for 1B is in "via departure hall B second level)" - does this include non-schengen?

Edit, as clarification was requested: I am not actually arriving in FRA. As there are no Priority Pass airside lounges in 1C, I was wondering whether the 1B lounges (for which Amex has an agreement) would be an option where I don't have to plan with a longer buffer time for security/immigration. I tried to phrase the question in a more general way so that it can be helpful for others.

Comment: Can you tell us which country you’re arriving from? Countries from most countries need to be rescreened, but flights from some countries like the USA or UK may not need to be.

Comment: It's actually a bit more complicated, see the edit. Apparently, I oversimplified it. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need to clear security when going from Terminal 1B to Terminal 1C.  The non-Schengen Skyline train station in 1C is outside of security, and requires you to pass through security in order to get to the C gates.  Presuming the lounge you are considering accessing is past immigration (I'm presuming it's the LH lounge at gate B42, which is) then you will not need to clear immigration again to get from there to 1C non-Schengen departures.

The best way to answer questions like this is to download the Lufthansa app, which provides an excellent map and even with step-by-step instructions between any 2 points in the airport - including listing immigration and security checkpoints.

Comment: According to the Lufthansa App from B to C involves a 13 minute walk, but no skyline train, or security.

Comment: @KristvanBesien Is that from non-Schengen to non-Schengen?  B and C both have Schengen areas and non-Schengen areas, and the path will be different.

Comment: Looking at the map that would be non-Schengen to non-Schengen. But it is not entirely clear. I just wanted to point out that the LH app is not going to give the correct answer either.
It depends partly on wether you arrive "clean" or not, and wether there is a clean route, which there sometimes is, and sometimes isn't in FRA. 
So in the end the usual advise applies: Just follow the signs.

Comment: @KristvanBesien The LH app is giving me the answer I expect - which involves security. For example, select gate B42 (the location of the lounge) to gate C14 (a non-Schengen gate in C)